# Saving a date to Firebase Firestore Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to find anywhere in the Web/Javascript docs anything about saving Dates to the Firestore. In `Swift`, I create a variable using `NSDate` and then Firebase is able to store that as a date object in the database. Is there similar functionality in Node.js? Can I use the [date-and-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time) package or is there native support for Dates in Node.js?

Comment: `new Date()` is the date object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Firestore documentation on saving data of supported types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types):

> ```
> var docData = {
>     stringExample: "Hello world!",
>     booleanExample: true,
>     numberExample: 3.14159265,
>     dateExample: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815")),
>     arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
>     nullExample: null,
>     objectExample: {
>         a: 5,
>         b: {
>             nested: "foo"
>         }
>     }
> };
> db.collection("data").doc("one").set(docData).then(function() {
>     console.log("Document successfully written!");
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I looked through a few of the pages where I thought it would be but I couldn't find it! 