# how to store date in the firebase with type 'timestamp' instead of 'map' from reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

From react application i'm getting date from a datepicker. i'm trying to save it on
firebase. It's saving properly in the database but not TYPE as 'timestamp', instead it's saving like 'map'. I'm sending data to firebase function created by us. from that function we are saving data to collection. any suggestion please.

```
const d = new Date("27-5-2021")
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(d)
(OR)
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(d.getTime())
```

[image]

Comment: Does this post answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345197/3833743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to do something like this to save it as timestamp on firebase.

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date).toDate());
```